# How to run a program just once with different entries?

Tags: python

I looked for an answer for my problem in the forum, but since I'm far from an expert, it is difficult to understand other cases and compare with mine. Sorry if it is an stupid question.

I'm doing a simple program in Python that reads a file `file_i`, receives some inputs, and returns a result `result_i`.

I want to run this program for 12 cases with 3 different files (`"file_05"`, `"file_10"` and `"file_20"`) and 4 different inputs (`u=7`, `u=8`, `u=9`, `u=10`). But I want to get the 12 results at once.

Currently, I am repeating the code 12 times and storing all the results in a file that contains `result_05_7`, `result_10_7`, ..., `result_20_10`. But of course it is not working well because every modification I make in the code I have to do 12 times...

Could anyone help me?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Comment: Follow @jonrsharpe's comment. This will also be useful: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/argparse.html

Comment: @ManojAwasthi only if the OP is making a command-line interface

Comment: True. I imagined that. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through your files and inputs and then store each result in a dictionary.

```
results = {}
files = ["file_05", "file_10", "file_20"]
inputs = [7, 8, 9, 10]
for file in files:
    results[file] = {}
    for input in inputs:
        result = yourfunc(file, input)
        results[file][input] = result
```

At the end, the results dictionary would contain all the entries:

```
{'file_05': {7: 18, 8: 19, 9: 14, 10: 7},
 'file_10': {7: 17, 8: 9,  9: 15, 10: 20},
 'file_20': {7: 8,  8: 4,  9: 15, 10: 15}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to do the following:

- read the documentation of `itertools`
- learn how to define functions.

This might help you:

```
import itertools

files = ["a.txt", "b.txt", "c.txt"]
numbers = [5,2,7,4,3,6,8,3]

def f(file, number):
    print "called f() for file", file, "with additional input", number

for f, n in itertools.product(files, numbers):
    f(f, n)
```

Please make sure that this example runs, try to understand it, *then* change it to your needs.